# iOS - How to solve echo problems with speex？

Tags: ios, objective-c, speex

My App call to the intercom has an echo, I have used the native method, but it is useless, I want to use the echo cancellation of speex, but I have encountered some problems, in the echo cancellation of speex, need three parameters, ref, echo and End, I only have the bufferList.mBuffers[0].mData variable, I don't know what the other two parameters are to be substituted for?

```
OSStatus recordingCallback(void *inRefCon, AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags, const AudioTimeStamp *inTimestamp, UInt32 inBusNumber, UInt32 inNumberFrames, AudioBufferList *ioData) {
AudioProcessor *audioProcessor = (__bridge AudioProcessor *)inRefCon;
AudioBufferList bufferList;
bufferList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
bufferList.mBuffers[0].mData = NULL;
OSStatus status = AudioUnitRender(audioProcessor.audioUnit, ioActionFlags, inTimestamp, inBusNumber, inNumberFrames, &bufferList);
if (status != noErr) {
    return status;
}
SpeexEchoState *echo_state = speex_echo_state_init(bufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize, 882);
SpeexPreprocessState *den = speex_preprocess_state_init(bufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize, 44100);
short *ref_buf = (short*)bufferList.mBuffers[0].mData;
short *echo_buf = (short*)malloc(bufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize);
short *endbuf = (short*)malloc(bufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize);
speex_echo_cancellation(echo_state,
                        (spx_int16_t*)ref_buf,
                        (spx_int16_t*)echo_buf,
                        (spx_int16_t*)endbuf);
speex_preprocess_run(den, (spx_int16_t*)endbuf);
[audioProcessor.delegate processAudioData:endbuf dataSize:bufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize];
free(ref_buf);
free(echo_buf);
free(endbuf);

return noErr;
```

}

Comment: Post your code in `code block` and not as a link to a picture.

Comment: very sorry! I just joined here, I don't have 10 reputation to post images.

Comment: Post code, not screenshot。

Answer (score 0):

If you build-in AEC is not working, it means that there is a good chance that your echo behavior is not trivial and you should look for more robust solutions than Speex. Google for echo cancellation software to find few alternatives.